# Optional spaces in font-lock-add-keywords expression

Tags: regex, emacs

I'm trying to add a simple "note" keyword using font-lock-add-keywords but I have difficulties specifying there may be optional spaces around. I've tried:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'lisp-mode
  '(("\\<\\([ ]+[Nn]ote[ ]+\\):" 1 face-admonition-note prepend)
    ))
```

But this does not work. It works in the regex-builder and it also works if I replace the `[ ]` with `[a]` for example. I'm certainly missing something obvious but I can't find it.

I also would like to restrict the keyword to the start of a line, so I added a `^` in front of the regex but with no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem. The `\\<` marking the start of a word (meaning anything but spaces) prevents the following `[ ]+` to be ever catched.